# Return value of promise from service to component

Tags: angular, async-await, es6-promise

I have a service class as follows

```
import { RetrieveMultipleResponse } from 'xrm-webapi/dist/models';

@Injectable()
export class CrmService {

   headers: any;
   error : any;
   store : Observable<any>;

   constructor(public crmDataService : CrmDataService) {}

   retrieveAllTeams(): Promise<RetrieveMultipleResponse> {
       return retrieveMultiple(this.crmDataService.config,"teams",null);
   }

}
```

And I'm calling it in the component like that:

```
load() {
    this.crmService.retrieveAllTeams()
        .then((results) => {
            if(results.value !== undefined && results.value !== null) {
                var teams = results.value;
            }
        },
        (error) => {

        });
}
```

So the `retrieveAllTeams` returns a Promise of type `RetrieveMultipleResponse`. The interface looks like that:

```
export interface RetrieveMultipleResponse {
    value: Entity[];
    '@odata.nextlink': string;
}
```

I would like to avoid using nested promises in my component so I am using Angular 6. I've tried to use `async` and `await` but I can't really figure out how to get results and the error from the `retrieveAllTeams` method in my component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to avoid using nested promises in my component so I am using Angular 6, I've tried to use async and await but cant really figure out how to get results and the error from the retrieveAllTeams

You can do it in this way:

```
async load() {

  // use try-catch block for handling errors
  try {
    // const result will have results from the 
    // retrieveAllTeams
    const result = await this.crmService.retrieveAllTeams();

    if (results.value !== undefined && results.value !== null) {
      var teams = results.value;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // catch errors if any
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```